# added "collision boundaries" code to my pygame program, now the sprites on-screen wont change when they need to

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a small test game on pygame where you need to fly a plane around the screen without touching the boundaries of the window, or the game will close down. Before I added the boundaries' code, I was able to make the plane's sprite change when it flew left or right, tilting in the respective direction. Now, although the "collision boundaries" code has nothing to do with the sprites code, the plane only remains in it's one, initial sprite and does not change (it still moves and the boundary code works fine, but the sprite itself wont change).

here's my code:

```
def game_loop():
        x = display_width * 0.45
        y = display_height * 0.8
        x_change = 0
        accel_x = 0
        y_change = 0
        accel_y = 0
        max_speed_x = 2.5
        max_speed_y = 2.5

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            gameExit = True
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a):
                               accel_x = -.2
                               img = pygame.image.load('PocketFlyer3.png')
                               img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))
                            elif event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d):
                               accel_x = .2
                               img = pygame.image.load('PocketFlyer2.png')
                               img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))
                            if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w):
                               accel_y = -.2
                            elif event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s):
                               accel_y = .2
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
                                    accel_x = 0
                                    img = pygame.image.load('PocketFlyer1.png')
                                    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))
                            if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s):
                                    accel_y = 0

    #accel script for X
            x_change += accel_x
            if abs(x_change) >= max_speed_x:
                    x_change = x_change/abs(x_change) * max_speed_x

            if accel_x == 0:
                    x_change *= 0.92

            x += x_change

    #accel script for Y

            y_change += accel_y
            if abs(y_change) >= max_speed_y:
                    y_change = y_change/abs(y_change) * max_speed_y

            if accel_y == 0:
                    y_change *= 0.92

            y += y_change

            display.fill(skyblue)
            plane(x,y)

            if x > display_width - plane_width or x < 0 or y > display_width - plane_width or y < 0:
                    gameExit = True

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
```

the width of the plane and the game's window is defined before this extract; nothing too important has been left out of this small extract either.
(the slight difference in the indentation of the code isn't the issue, only something that's occurred whilst posting this question)

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we can't help much with the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Your boundary test is wrong (checks both `x` and `y` against `width` and ignores `height`), should be:

```
if (x > display_width - plane_width) \
        or (x < 0) \
        or (y > display_height - plane_height) \
        or (y < 0):
```